# JBoss Guvnor, can I create arrays and/or maps in a Declarative Model?

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine

I'm using Drools Guvnor in JBoss.  I am creating a Declarative Model object.  I can add simple types such as String, Boolean, etc.  Is it possible to add an array, List and/or Map in my object?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use Lists and Maps in your declarative model.

I used Drools Guvnor 5.5.0.Final and did like this:

1. Create New declarative model
2. Add new fact type: 
   Name: Person
3. Add fields:
   name: String 
   drink: String
4. Add new fact type: 
   Name: Party
5. Add fields:
   people: java.util.List

If you click 'View Source' you should get something like this:

```
declare Person
    name: String
    drink: String
end

declare Party
    people: java.util.List
end
```

To use the model, I created a 'Technical rule' in Guvnor looking like this:

```
when
then
      Person pa = new Person();
      pa.setName("A");
      pa.setDrink("Lager");
      Person pb = new Person();
      pb.setName("B");
      pb.setDrink("IPA");
      Party p = new Party();
      p.setPeople(new java.util.ArrayList());
      p.getPeople().add(pa);
      p.getPeople().add(pb);

      insert(pa);
      insert(pb);
      insert(p);
```

Generics don't seem to work well in drools. I got some compilation errors when I built the package.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not possible (from trying and reading the docu). I've read that in Guvnor you can extend classes from an existing POJO-model (jar) and make them declarative this way.